# How does vtable handle multiple inheritance?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, vtable

I understand that for single inheritance a pointer to a virtual function table is added to determine what parent class functions to call at runtime.

```
class Genius {
    int IQ;
public:
    virtual void brag();
};

class Me : public Genius {
    int age;
};
```

When instantiated, the memory layout of `Me` should look something like

```
  pointer to Genius vtable
  int iq
  int age
```

But what happens in the case of multiple inheritance?

```
// Assume CoolDude has virtual functions as well
class Me : public Genius, public CoolDude {
    int age;
};
```

What does the memory layout of the `Me` class look like now? How is multiple inheritance handled?

Comment: The memory layout is implementation defined.

Comment: More curious to see how it is handled at all. An explanation of any implementation is welcome. Does the implementation really differ drastically between the major compilers?

Comment: It's in the D&E book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class will have 2 pointers to vtables, one to its implementation of `Genius` and one to its implementation of `CoolDude`. When casting to a base class, the the returned pointer will differ from the original by the offset of the vtable(and other members) or the base class.

Comment: So the memory layout from top to bottom is something like `vtable1, vars1, vtable2, vars2, local stuff`?

Comment: Yes but try it and see for yourself.